# When I create a variable in create procedure on mySQL I get an error

Tags: mysql, sql

//This is the code

```
create procedure st_insertRole(
@name varchar(30)  //I get the error here
as
insert into roles values(@name)
);
```

here is the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My SQL does not allow session variables to be used for procedure parameters.  You also have parentheses misplaced.  The code in MySQL would look more like:

```
delimiter $$

create procedure st_insertRole (
    in_name varchar(30)
) 
begin
    insert into roles (name)
        values (in_name);
end; $$
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wrong

```
create procedure st_insertRole(
name_ varchar(30) )
insert into roles values(name_)
;
```